# Issue detecting external hdd on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, external-hard-drive

I have two HDD on my Ubuntu machine. One is a Maxtor 320Gb and the other is a Verbatim 1.5Tb. While it automatically recognizes the first one as sdb1 it doesn't recognize the latter. I can't see it on fdisk either. Any fix for this?

Comment: If you make the output  of `dmesg` available at a site like http://pastebin.org/ it would really help